# Pandas convert values with commas to new value

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have a column in a pandas df that looks like this:

```
  specialty
0 1
1 2,5
2 2
3 6
4 missing
5 1
6 3
7 1,3,4
8 4
9 1
```

And I'd like to convert all the values with more than one value to `7`, and convert all "missing" to 6. I know for that I can do `df['specialty'].replace({'missing':6})`. But not sure for the conversion of multiple values to `7`  Output would look like:

```
  specialty
0 1
1 7
2 2
3 6
4 6
5 1
6 3
7 7
8 4
9 1
```

I've tried `df['specialty'].str.contains(',') = 7` but that gives

```
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) or
[`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
df['specialty'] = np.select([df['specialty'].str.contains(','),
                             df['specialty'].eq('missing')], [7, 6], 
                             default=df['specialty'])
```

---

```
df['specialty'] = np.where(df['specialty'].str.contains(','), 
                           7, 
                           df['specialty'].replace({'missing':6}))

print (df)
  specialty
0         1
1         7
2         2
3         6
4         6
5         1
6         3
7         7
8         4
9         1
```

Comment: @hulio_entredas I think `select` should be faster here.

Comment: Gotcha. For some reason the `np.where` version changed `missing` to 7 in my full data set, but the `select` worked as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df['specialty'].str.contains(','), 'specialty'] = 7
df.loc[df['specialty'].eq('missing'), 'specialty'] = 6
```

Output:

```
  specialty
0         1
1         7
2         2
3         6
4         6
5         1
6         3
7         7
8         4
9         1
```

You might also want to calculate from the real values (2+5 -> 7):

```
df['specialty'] = [6 if s=='missing' else sum(map(int, s.split(',')))
                   for s in df['specialty']]
```

Or:

```
df['specialty'] = (df['specialty'].replace({'missing': '6'})
                   .str.split(',', expand=True).astype(float)
                   .sum(axis=1).astype(int)
                  )
```

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "calculate from the real values"?

Comment: `1,3,4` could also be seen as `1+3+4`, I know this wasn't your original logic but it might still be interesting

Comment: Oh I see, not what I'm looking for but still useful!

Comment: But the first part is doing what you asked ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
df['spe2'] = (df['specialty'].astype(str).replace({'missing': '6'})
                             .str.split(',').explode().astype(int)
                             .groupby(level=0).sum())
print(df)

# Output
  specialty  spe2
0         1     1
1       2,5     7
2         2     2
3         6     6
4   missing     6
5         1     1
6         3     3
7     1,3,4     8
8         4     4
9         1     1
```